# How to specify out and in parameters?

Tags: java, documentation, javadoc

I'm writing some javadoc, and was wondering how to emphasize an out parameter.

I'm currently doing this (pretty straightforward)

```
/**
 * @param cl        (IN Parameter)  description here <br/>
 * @param nodes     (OUT Parameter) description here <br/>
 * @param holotypes (OUT Parameter) description here <br/>
 */
public void getNodes(List<O> cl, List<Node<O>> nodes, List<O> holotypes) {...}
```

Comment: Personally I try to avoid out parameters and instead return an object that contains what would be the out parameters.  I find that the code is usually much better that way.

Comment: @TofuBeer So do I, but cant do it when I have to return 2 lists. Two separate methods is not possible here, so this is what i have. Returning one list and passing the other one as an out param. is the worst option IMHO.

Comment: You could return List[] and document that it will always be of size 2. Or you could create a class that wraps 2 Lists (like a struct).

Comment: +1 @Steve Kuo I like the wrapper class idea, but if its a private method, i'd also return an array

Answer (score 7):

Strictly speaking you cannot implement OUT parameters in Java.  All parameters are IN and are passed by value ... where the value is a reference for reference types.

In your example, the parameters *seem* to behave rather like OUT parameters because they are mutable collections.  But this is an illusion.  For example:

```
    res = null;
    make(res);
    assert res != null;  // this would succeed with a real OUT parameter

    public void make(List<String> p /* OUT parameter */) {
        p = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
```

Now, if you feel like labelling these parameters "IN" and "OUT" parameters in your project documentation, that's fine (provided that you clearly document what you mean by the labels).

But you won't normally see this terminology used in javadocs, because strictly speaking it is **incorrect** ... relative to the standard terminology taught in comparative programming language courses since at least the 1970's.

Answer (score 3):

Your javadoc looks fine to me. clear and understandable. Don't forget to add that the lists *have* to be created and *have* to be moodifiable, otherwise the method might complain with nasty exceptions. So much for the answer.

But I suggest you do not use `out` parameters unless you're forced to do so (like if you have to implement 3rd party interfaces or you have to use JNDI).

The method is named `getNodes` so most programmers expect, that the method returns an array or a collection of nodes. But in this case, the method populates two passed lists with nodes and holotypes.

So if your free to choose the method signature, I suggest you declare it like this:

```
public List<O> getNodes(List<O> cl) {
  List<O> result = pickAllNodesFromList(cl);
  return result;
}

public List<O> getHolotypes(List<O> cl) {
  List<O> result = pickAllHolotypesFromList(cl);
  return result;
}
```

or declare a special type for the class, like:

```
class CLTypes<O> {
  List<O> nodes = new ArrayList<O>();
  List<O> holotypes = new ArrayList<O>();

  CLTypes(List<O> cl) {
    nodes.addAll(pickAllNodes(cl));
    holotypes.addAll(pickAllNodes(cl));
  }

  // getters for the nodes
  // ...

  // private methods to pick objects for source list
  // ...
}
```

and implement the method like this:

```
public CLTypes<O> getNodes(List<O> cl) {
  return new CLTypes<O>(cl);
}
```

---

If you need to return two lists (as I read from the comments above), another easy solution could be wrapping the two lists in a map:

```
public Map<String, List<O>> getNodes(List<O> cl) {
  Map<String, List<O>> result = new HashMap<String, List<O>>();
  result.put("nodes", pickAllNodes(cl));
  result.put("holotypes", pickAllHolotypes(cl));
  return result;
}
```

Comment: You're welcome :) just ignore them, if you can't change the method signature ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could create annotations In and Out.  Annotate these annotations with the Documented annotation.  I *think* that you can apply annotations to parameters in the very latest JAVA.  (If you can't then disregard this answer.)  These annotations should show up in your javadocs.